# Is it possible to include Mysql.Data in .exe or application files?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have an application written in C# which is connecting to database using Mysql.Data.dll reference. Is it possible to run this program on another computer without installing MySQL Connector etc. and just include all files needed in program directory/.exe file?

Comment: Have you tried setting the MySQL.Data.dll to copy local?  Also if this is a click once application you can go into properties of the project and then go to the publish tab, click on Application Files, and find the MySQL.Data.Dll in there and set publish status to include.

Comment: Ok it seems i had to add Mysql.Data.dll to Application Files folder, thanks a lot!

Comment: Awesome added my response as a answer as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the MySQL.Data.dll to copy local. Also if this is a click once application you can go into properties of the project and then go to the publish tab, click on Application Files, and find the MySQL.Data.Dll in there and set publish status to include.

Comment: Whoever reads this, make sure you find the <reference /> entry in the .csproj and check to make sure there's a <Private>true</Private> element as a child. Sometimes, visual studio doesn't persist this properly to csproj and this can play havoc if someone else checks out the project and tries to build.

Comment: This answer was exactly what I was looking for, and plus 1 for the reference tip.